# Where can i get MatrixStats?

Tags: iis, logging

I run several IIS web servers and want to install some sort of log reader.

A lot of the big boys use MatrixStats, however a good hard Google has come up blank on who makes it and/or where I can get it from to install on my own servers.

I have looked at AwStats but my god its complicated to get working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this knowledge base article](http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/productKB/default.asp?article=Fasthosts/MatrixStats), MatrixStats is owned by FastHosts.co.uk and is available only to their customers.

You could use Google Analytics, or try one of the following programs:

- [IIS Log Analyzer](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1864&g=6)
- [Weblog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com/info/IISLogs.htm)
- [Easy AWstats for IIS instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/50526/setting-up-awstats-on-windows-server-and-iis/)